# Can I use excel to work out how something is being calculated by giving it an example output?

Tags: excel

I have 2 columns in excel.

Column 1 indicates '**pieces**' (of delivery) and the other indicates '**processing time**'.

I typed these in by hand because i was given them on a sheet of paper, so there is no maths formula visible.

Is there a way to get Excel to tell me how 'Process time' is being calculated because I really can't figure it out.

**--- Example of situation ---**

**Total pieces   |   Pro Time (MM:SS)**
40   |  00:21
3   |   00:01
12   |   00:04
43   |   00:22

Comment: `21/40`, `1/3`, etc....

Comment: But it should be the same formula for all values

Comment: Lol, Mr T I think findwindow is pulling your chain. There is no way for us to determine some relationship between # of pieces and the time. I can see that its not linear. You have to look at the process that generates these numbers and where they come from. Could not possible tell if it comes from some Excel formula without knowing more about the context.

Comment: Yea, it ranges from .3 to .5 but this is kind of silly no? I mean, do you expect all humans to process at exactly the same efficiency?

Comment: It makes sense the average is lower for fewer pieces so you'd want to build assessments with tiers and only question those that fall below that particular mean/median.

Comment: Or who even knows if its manual processing time. Could be a script, fabrication machines, etc. I would probably have to say that this question is out of scope for SO though I couldn't be able to articulate why ;p.

Comment: @nbayly delivery is done by a human as of today?

Comment: Who knows. The question as posted is to overly broad and does not relate to an issue with coding. I think I'm ready to move on.

Comment: You could sort it and put it in a xy chart... there you can show "average curves" and also the formulas for them... it may be not the exact answer, but you should get close to it... the formulas are mainly like `ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e`

Comment: Actually it looks pretty much linear.

Process time ~= ttl_pcs*0.55-1.48